# Unable to get props while testing with jest Enzyme React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-props

My Component Code:

```
import React from 'react'
export default class InfoViewComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      counter: 1,
      activeTab: '1',
    }
  }
  render () {
    const data = this.props.data
    return (
      <section className="dish">
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col>
                  <h1 className="display-1">{data.title}</h1>
                  <Button  onClick={this.handleAddToCart} >Add to Cart</Button>
                  <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Place order</Button>
                </div>
                <p>{data.description}</p>

                <div>
                  <ButtonGroup>
                    <Button>-</Button>
                    <Button>{this.state.counter}</Button>
                  </ButtonGroup>
                 </div>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Testing Code

```
import React from 'react'
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import InfoViewComponent from './InfoViewComponent'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })


describe('Info Component', () => {
  it('Should be defined', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<InfoViewComponent />)
    expect(wrapper.find(InfoViewComponent)).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

data:

```
"menus": [
    {
      "code": "h8",
      "title": "Some Text",
      "type": "Some Text",
      "description": "Some Text",
      "images": [],
      "keywords": [
        "Some Text",
        "Some Text"
      ],
      "price": "3",
      "about": "Some Text,
     ],
    },
  ]
```

I'm unable to get all the props from my component to the testing code.
I get error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".
I need help on how to do this.
Added data to understand. I get the data from firebase in one component and pass it as it as props to InfoViewComponent that is to be tested.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share us MyComponent full code and how this.props.data looks like

Comment: Sure, I have updated the code

Comment: share your data as well which is this.props.data. The issue would be the data is available but title key doesn't exist or the data is undefined and when you try to access it will be undefined. So to understand further we want to see how your data looks like and from wr you are passing the data to MyComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the title when the data is undefined. So what you have to do is check whether the data is undefined or not and only then access its fields like below

```
      {data && data != undefined && (<Row>
        <Col>
              <h1 className="display-1">{data.title}</h1>
              <Button  onClick={this.handleAddToCart} >Add to Cart</Button>
              <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Place order</Button>
            </div>
            <p>{data.description}</p>

            <div>
              <ButtonGroup>
                <Button>-</Button>
                <Button>{this.state.counter}</Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
             </div>
      </Row>)}
```

Comment: Sure will do :)